# No object movement animation

Tags: flash, object, actionscript-2, move

I recently started flash programming, I have problems with a move function that dose not show the movement,

the code i use:

```
function cardmove(card){
    xDiff=(playerHand+space+card.width)-card._x;
    yDiff=(Stage.height/2+space)-card._y;
        speedx =xDiff/10;
        speedy =yDiff/10; 
    for (frame=0;frame<10;frame++){
         card._x+=speedx;
         card._y+=speedy;}
    playerHand = card._x ;
}
```

the card is in place it should be right on start, and no movement is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Flash does not refresh the layout during a loop.
If you want to move something, you have to give the hand back to flash between two steps.

You have two main way to do it, the setInterval :

```
// You need to declare this variables to access them in the function "applyMovement"
var _nInterval:Number;
var _nSteps:Number;

// Yout function
function cardmove(card){
    xDiff=(playerHand+space+card.width)-card._x;
    yDiff=(Stage.height/2+space)-card._y;
    speedx =xDiff/10;
    speedy = yDiff / 10; 

    // Set the steps to 10
    _nSteps = 10;
    // Before start the setInterval, you have to stop a previous one
    clearInterval(_nInterval);
    // You call the function each 41 ms (about 24 fps) with the parameters
    setInterval(this, "applyMovement", 41, card, speedx, speedy);
}
// This function apply the new coodinates
function applyMovement(mc:MovieClip, nX:Number, nY:Number) {
    if (_nSteps >= 0) {
        mc._x += nX;
        mc._y += nY;
    }else {
        clearInterval(_nInterval);
    }
    _nSteps --;
}
```

or the onEnterFrame :

```
// You need to declare this variables to access them in the function "applyMovement"
var _nSteps:Number;
var _mc:MovieClip;
var _nX:Number;
var _nY:Number;

// Yout function
function cardmove(card){
    xDiff=(playerHand+space+card.width)-card._x;
    yDiff=(Stage.height/2+space)-card._y;
    _nX =xDiff/10;
    _nY = yDiff / 10; 

    _mc = card;

    // Set the steps to 10
    _nSteps = 10;
    // You have to use the Delegate function to access to the "good" this in the function
    this.onEnterFrame = mx.utils.Delagate.create(this,applyMovement);
}
// This function apply the new coodinates
function applyMovement() {
    if (_nSteps >= 0) {
        _mc._x += nX;
        _mc._y += nY;
    }else {
        delete this.onEnterFrame;
    }
    _nSteps --;
}
```